# typesetting spaces in initials in German texts

Tags: kerning, white-space

Assuming you are preparing a German text (say, to be published with Springer), what would be a "standard" way to typeset spaces in a name, say, Edsger Wybe Dijkstra, in which the initials are abbreviated:

1. `E.W.\@ Dijkstra` (or `E.W. Dijkstra`)
2. `E.\@ W.\@ Dijkstra` (or `E. W. Dijkstra`)
3. `E.\,W.\@ Dijkstra` (or `E.\,W. Dijkstra`)
4. `E.\kern.02em W.\@ Dijkstra` (or `E.\kern.02em W. Dijkstra`)

In case 4., what would be the "correct" kerning amount?

Comment: why not the simplest `E. W.  Dijkstra` ? (or `E.~W.~Dijkstra`  if you are in a context that could linebreak)

Comment: I don't typeset German texts, but I am of German descent and did spend a night in a Holiday Inn Express `:^)`  I opt for #4, with the proper kern being `\,`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes isn't that the same as 3?

Comment: Personally, I would opt for 3 (I use that in some of my German texts).

Comment: well, the `\@` are not doing anything so just using a space is simpler than using `\@` in all four case. I would not use 4 as the numerical value is font-dependent. so `E. W. Dijkstra` or `E.\,W. Dijkstra`

Comment: That is the default after a capital letter

Comment: yes, If you need to end a sentence with a capital then `X\@. ` will do that.

Comment: TeX has that convention to make it easy to enter people's initials.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I need new glasses.

Comment: @user49915 em is not enough really, some fonts even of the same design size are designed for closer spacing than others. Inter-word space is more font-dependent than simply using 1em`

Comment: This is mostly a stylistic issue. Take a few books from reputed publishers, possibly in the same field as your document, look at how the books do and decide. The most important thing is that you're consistent in the same document; the second most important aspect is that no line break should be allowed between initial(s) and name.

Comment: @user49915 Typesetting in narrow columns requires compromises. If you care about typography, you will ponder in what cases a line break in a normally bad place should be allowed.

Comment: @egreg IIRC the TeXBook shows Knuth typesetting his own name with no linebreak between the two initials, but a break permitted between the pair of initials and the surname. But I agree that a *single* initial should not end a line.

Comment: Well Knuth only had two initials, and I didn't generalize to $n \ne 2$. I was  giving a counterexample to your assertion "no line break should be allowed between initial(s) and name."  Anyway, my memory was right: line 19002 of `textbook.tex` has  "`D.~E. Knuth and M.~F. Plass, ``Breaking paragraphs …`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book “[Detailtypografie](https://typografie.de/produkt/detailtypografie/)” by Forssmann and de Jong recommends the following

> **Innerhalb** von Abkürzungs-Gebilden und von Daten steht ein Flexibles Leerzeichen » «.
>
> **Am Ende** der Abkürzung und nach dem Datum steht ein Wortzwischenraum » «.

Translation (mine):

> **Within** abbreviation compounds and dates a flexible space » « is placed.
>
> **At the end** of an abbreviation or after a date an interword space » « is placed.

If I were to translate this to LaTeX, that would be

```
E.\,W.\ Dijkstra
```

or, using the convention that TeX does not treat a period after a capital as full stop, we may omit the explicit space `\␣`

```
E.\,W. Dijkstra
```

It is not entirely correct because the `\,` thin space is a `\kern.16667em` whereas the “flexible space”, as Forssmann and de Jong call it, is supposed to be `\kern.25em` (4/M space, de: Viertelgeviert, U+2005).

Initials should not be separated which is why the `\,` in `E.\,W.` is a `\kern` which is unbreakable.  If, however, a situation arises where this leads to a problematic line break, they may be split, i.e. the `\kern` can be replaced by `\hskip`.